# What is the least system demanding way to create a project allocation table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, backend

I have a list of projects.
For each projects I have a list of project members.
For each project member I have a list of allocated time (week33 100%, week34 80% and so on)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Project name | 3 resources |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Resource | Role        | 33  |  34 |  35 |  36 |  37 |  38 | 
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Person 1 | Developer   | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Person 2 | UX designer | 100 | 100 | 100 |  60 |  60 |  60 |
| Person 3 | Project Mng | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If MySQL had (dynamic) PIVOT tables, I could do most of the work there. But no such luck.

<s>If I start using Joins and unions, I will get very big resultsets when I have 50+ projects with at least 10 project members with allocation accross 36 weeks.</s>
If I start building a query to fetch all the data in one go, I think I will be getting a very big and complicated query. I'm not that skilled in MySQL, so I'm just assuming here from past experience.

```
SELECT p.project_name, r.resource, r.role 
FROM projects p 
LEFT JOIN link_allocation la ON p.id = la.fk_project_id
LEFT JOIN resources r ON la.fk_resource_id = r.id
UNION
SELECT * from allocation a
WHERE.... and so on
```

I could run 3 queries, returning Projects, Resources and Allocation. Then loop through using javascript (data is returned using Node.js)

```
for (var i in Projects){ 
  for (var i in Resouces){ 
    for (var i in Allocation){ 
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm concerned about is, what will be the least taxing way of implementing it?

Can some joins be done on MySQL then the rest done in JS backend?

And I will assume this is a fairly "common" scenario, so I'm also assuming that someone have developed a library to tackle this problem. Does anyone know of anything?

My tables look more or less like this:

```
Projects
| ID | name | fk_project_owner_id | fk_project_mng_id |

Resources
| ID | name | role |

Allocations
| fk_project_id | fk_resource_id | week_nr | allocation |

Link_tbl_projects_resources
| fk_project_id | fk_resource_id |
```

Comment: `If I start using Joins and unions, I will get very big resultsets when I have 50+ projects with at least 10 project members with allocation accross 36 weeks.` Nonsense.

Comment: Ok, poor choice of explanation. But the SQL Query to get all the data in one go will be, if not horrific, very big / bad? :)

Comment: Not even close. 50x10x36 = 18000. That's not even a burp to a properly designed and  indexed MySQL database.

Comment: The query, not the result. The query will be quite complicated. But for a super expert, maybe not. (I'm primarly a frontend developer)

Comment: I have an alternative solution for that, but I can't answer

Comment: I think you're talking about joining something in the region of 3 to 5 tables. I don't think that that's particularly complicated. In general, the fewer hits on the database, the better.

Comment: Yes, 4 tables. Projects, Resources, Allocation and on link table for linking projects and resources. Allocation table has foreign keys for project and resource. But I'm shit on using joins.